# How to write Unit Testing with Dagger 2 Subcomponent

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, dagger-2

I'm just starting to use Dagger 2 in my Android application, And I'm trying to write Unit Tests that their Modules are defined as Subcomponents.

I've read Google's post about [Testing with Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html). And this very helpful [Medium post](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-testing-using-dagger-2-mockito-and-a-custom-junit-rule-c8487ed01b56) as well. But I only found examples on how to test with Components but not Subcomponents. And I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of code you would like to test, and describe exactly what you want to test? What use case would be considered a failure?

Answer (score 0):

Separate injector/provider methods from Component interface.

This is for example:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
  fun uploadComponent(module: UploadModule): UploadComponent
}
```

```kotlin
@Subcomponent(modules = [UploadModule::class])
interface UploadComponent : UploadInjector {
}
```

```kotlin
interface UploadInjector {
  fun inject(it: UploadWorker)
}
```

And then you can introduce `UploadInjector` to production code regardless whether it instantiated with production or test environment.

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [TestAppModule::class])
interface TestAppComponent {
  fun uploadComponent(module: TestUploadModule): TestUploadComponent
}
```

```kotlin
@Subcomponent(modules = [TestUploadModule::class])
interface TestUploadComponent : UploadInjector {
}
```